# Mount: permission denied installing docker CE on debian 9

Tags: linux, docker, debian

We're having a problem installing docker Ce on a machine with debian 9

we started with debian 8, and upgrade it to 9 because the documentation for docker on 8 wasn't as good

right now whenever we try to install it, dpkg throws this

```
Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.14~3-0~debian-stretch) ...
mount: permission denied
mount: permission denied
mount: permission denied
mount: permission denied
/etc/init.d/docker: 96: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
```

i don't get why the permission denied

and the ulimit is set for 16000 on -n

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux tools/apps. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Obvious question: Did you run with `sudo`? When asking a question about a command that fails it is a good idea to always show the exact command.

Comment: i'm running everything as a root, oh, sorry i didn't know that preparing a machine for deplyment was not releated. i'll try those forums, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On debian derivatives, upgrading a system without disabling third party repository is possible and allowed in the latest Ubuntu releases.

But on Debian, you need to disable the third party repository (docker-ce) to smoothly upgrade from jessie to stretch. Once done you can enable it by replacing jessie by stretch in your sources.list.

On debian, third party repository doesn't follow the main sources.list upgrade, for lack of dependencies the packages won't be upgraded and its services will fail to restart as expected.

Comment: i have had remove everithing related to docker before upgrading :c